# Use the command if any in a 3D array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, any

I have a n-by-m-by-3 multidimensional array like this:

val(:,:,1) =

```
 1     0     1     1     1
 1     0     1     1     1
 1     0     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     0     1
 1     1     1     0     1
 1     0     1     1     1
```

val(:,:,2) =

```
 1     1     1     1     1
 1     1     1     0     1
 1     1     1     0     1
 1     0     1     1     1
 1     0     1     1     1
 1     0     1     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1
```

val(:,:,1) =

```
 1     1     0     1     1
 1     1     0     1     1
 1     1     1     1     1
 1     0     1     1     1
 1     0     1     1     0
 1     1     1     1     0
 1     1     1     1     0
```

And I want to say to Matlab: for each row, check if any of the element is 0, and then create a n-by-1-by-3 matrix (or alternatively 3 n-by-1 matrices) of the type:

val(:,:,1) =

```
 1
 0
 0
 1
 1
```

where a 0 corresponds to a "yes, at least one of the elements of that row was 0" and a 1 corresponds to "no, every element of that row was a 1".

I tried with

```
for a = 1:n
   for b = 1: 3
       if any (A,2) ==0
       B (n,1,3)= 0;
       else 
       B (n,1,3)= 1;
       end
   end
end
```

or just:

```
B= any(A,2) ==0
```

but it doesn't work, I always obtain a (n,1,3) array of all zeros.

Many thanks!

Comment: And you've tried using the `any` function...?

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is

```
~all(val, 2)
```

You can use

```
any(~val, 2)
```

if you insist on using `any`.

Some MATLAB functions accept an argument that specifies on which dimension you want to apply them.